# Spring AOP with AspectJ - Load time weaving doubts

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop

Reading the `Spring AOP` documentation ([link](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-aj-ltw)), I'm having a hard time (maybe also because english is not my native language) understanding these paragraphs.

First, I read

> Further, in certain environments, this support enables load-time
>   weaving without making any modifications to the application server’s
>   launch script that is needed to add
>   `-javaagent:path/to/aspectjweaver.jar` or (as we describe later in
>   this section)
>   `-javaagent:path/to/org.springframework.instrument-{version}.jar`
>   (previously named `spring-agent.jar`).

And

> Developers modify one or more files that form the application context
>   to enable load-time weaving

Which files? `@Aspect` classes and `aop.xml` files?

---

Then, when describing an example in the same sub-chapter, they say

> We have one last thing to do. The introduction to this section did say
>   that one could switch on LTW selectively on a per-`ClassLoader` basis
>   with Spring, and this is true. **However, for this example**, we use a
>   Java agent (supplied with Spring) to switch on the LTW. We use the
>   following command to run the Main class shown earlier:

And they apply a `Java Agent` to the JVM.

```
-javaagent:C:/projects/foo/lib/global/spring-instrument.jar
```

---

Now I have a couple of doubts.

If I `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving`, do I need the `spring-instrument` Jar file as `Java Agent`?
I suppose the answer is yes, because we need to add bytecode to the `class` file before loading it. But a confirmation would be much appreciated.

The Jar naming is a little ambiguos, first they mention `spring-agent.jar`, then they use `org.springframework.instrument-{version}.jar`, and then `spring-instrument.jar`.
Are we always talking about the same Jar file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see from another question you asked that you are using Spring Boot and running a fat jar. In this case you don't need `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` or `spring-instrument` (formerly known as `spring-agent`). Just ignore them if you are not running in an appserver for which you don't control the agent path.

I opened an issue for you about the confusion in the docs: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22429.