# AspectJ : how to limit which aspects are targeted

Tags: java, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop, instrumentation

I am trying to enable aspect weaving for private methods on a large spring boot project.  I already have aspects targeting public methods working just fine but my research led me to the notion that Spring AOP aspects can only interact with public methods.

I came across this project which I have incorporated into my code (literally copy-pasting the usage example) :

https://github.com/subes/invesdwin-instrument

This has the side effect of HUNDREDS of aspects being targeted at startup (spring stuff mostly). The console messages look like this :

```
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
[AppClassLoader@277050dc] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type javax.servlet.Filter
when processing declare parents org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean
when processing type mungers 
when weaving
```

How do i configure aspectJ to only work with the aspects I am creating and ignore the rest?

******UPDATE******

I followed the recommendation in the comments and now i have the following exception on startup :

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:org.springframework.instrument.jar
```

Do i need to add both aspectjweaver and spring-instrument java agents?

Comment: You can advise private methods with compile-time weaving, such that you do not require a special weaver agent in your JVM. Here is a repo with a bunch of examples: https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-aspectj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first, the project you linked relies on you running the Oracle JVM.
Infact, it uses the `sun.misc.unsafe` class, which is also more difficult to use starting from JDK 9 (JPMS).

Anyway, that project will discover a `META-INF/aop.xml` file, which points to the classes containing your aspects. An example of that file content might be

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
    <weaver>
        <include within="your.package.aspects.*"/>
        <include within="your.package.one.*"/>
    </weaver>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="your.package.aspects.YourClassAspect"/>
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

Inside the `<weaver>` tag you're defining which classes will be considered for weaving.
Your pointcuts then tells AspectJ which specific methods to weave.

But keep reading.

---

I don't recommend using that project, especially if you're running the latest releases of Spring.

Just

- attach the AspectJ `aspectjweaver.jar`(and **maybe** also `spring-instrument.jar`, see docs) agent
- define an `aop.xml` file under `META-INF`
- define your pointcuts using annotations
- if necessary (see docs) add the `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` annotation

and you're good to go.

For further reading see [AOP docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop), and a couple of questions I asked some time ago, which produced a documentation update (see [diff](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/3eb1042a53fa5daf9ae4d550dbe245f9754bfb73)).

[AspectJ LTW (weaving) not working with Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54749106/aspectj-ltw-weaving-not-working-with-spring-boot)
[Spring AOP with AspectJ - Load time weaving doubts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54746336/spring-aop-with-aspectj-load-time-weaving-doubts)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!  I am indeed using Java 11 so naturally i want to move away from the old garbage you mentioned!  I did what you recommended (added -javaagent:lib/aspectjweaver-1.9.2.jar to my vm arguments in the eclipse run configuration, created the aop.xml file, added the EnableLoadTimeWeaving annotation to a config class).  Now i have an exception on startup which i will add to my main post.

Comment: Wow, just saw that you literally wrote that might be a possibility.  I am tired lol.  Trying now.

Comment: @Martin you might also want to try **removing** the `EnableLoadTimeWeaving` annotation, while keeping only `aspectjweaver-1.9.2.jar`. It all depends on the environment unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks to your input i got everything to work.  Thanks!

Comment: @Martin awesome! Which setup did you end up with?

Comment: both agents attached, aop.xml containing the package i want to "scan" and the aspects i have created, logger classes (aspects) with pointcuts representing which methods i want to intercept and the @EnableLoadTimeWeaving annotation.  I am now able to intercept private methods.

Comment: and no, i did not use com.sun.Unsafe :P